# select multiselect values using group_concat and left join

Tags: mysql, left-join

so i am making a simple Movies database using PHP and MySQL. I have two tables:

**Movies**

```
ID  | Title           | Genre    
-----------------------------
1   | The Dark Knight | 1,2
2   | Man of steel    | 3,4
3   | SpiderMan       | 5,6
```

**moviesgenre**

```
ID  | genre    
------------------------
1   | Action
2   | Adventure
3   | Animation
4   | Biography
5   | Comedy
6   | Crime
```

and this is my query

```
SELECT movies.*, GROUP_CONCAT(moviesgenre.genre) as genres
FROM movies    
LEFT JOIN moviesgenre ON movies.genre = moviesgenre.id
```

Here is the result i'm currently getting:

```
ID  | Title           | Genres  | Genres    
-------------------------------------------
1   | The Dark Knight | 1,2     | Action,Animation,Comedy
```

The output i expect:

```
ID  | Title           | Genres  | Genres    
-------------------------------------------
1   | The Dark Knight | 1,2     | Action,Adventure
2   | Man of steel    | 3,4     | Animation,Biography
3   | SpiderMan       | 5,6     | Comedy,Crime
```

Is this possible, and if so, how?

Comment: What output do you expect ?

Comment: See normalisation and amend your schema accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the MySQL function [FIND_IN_SET](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-find_in_set-function.php) to achieve what you want. You also need to group your query by the movies.

[I've set up this SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b969a/14) to show how you could implement it.

Your query will then end up looking something like this:

```
SELECT movies.*, GROUP_CONCAT(moviegenres.genre) AS genre
FROM movies    
LEFT JOIN moviegenres ON FIND_IN_SET(moviegenres.id, movies.genre)
GROUP BY movies.id
```

Comment: Thanks for the downvote.. Please leave a comment if you feel there is something wrong with the answer.

Comment: How does this not contribute to his question? It gives the OP the expected result for the query he is trying to build, and refers to documentation on the implemented code.

Comment: The OP misunderstands a fundamental concept of Relational Database Management, i.e. normalisation. Any answer that fails to address this simply perpetuates the error.

Comment: thank you very much,  works like charm, and again the down vote wasn't me

Comment: and FYI i  can't vote because of the less of 15 reputation

Answer (score 4):

According to Entity Relations DB rules, you should add a table to your DB for the many to many relation needed, and modify your Movies table:

Movies

```
ID  | Title             
-----------------------------
1   | The Dark Knight 
2   | Man of steel    
3   | SpiderMan
```

Movies_Genre

```
Movie_ID  | Genre_ID    
-----------------------------
1   | 1
1   | 2
2   | 3
2   | 4
3   | 5
3   | 6
```

Genres

```
ID  | genre    
------------------------
1   | Action
2   | Adventure
3   | Animation
4   | Biography
5   | Comedy
6   | Crime
```

The SQL then becomes:

```
   SELECT Movies.*, GROUP_CONCAT(Genres.ID), GROUP_CONCAT(Genres.genre)
   FROM   Movies INNER JOIN 
          Movies_Genre ON Movies.ID = Movies_Genre.Movie_ID 
   INNER JOIN Genres ON  Movies_Genre.Genre_ID = Genres.ID
   GROUP BY Movies.ID
```

OR

You could use the FIND_IN_SET statement in your WHERE clause:

```
SELECT movies.*,
       GROUP_CONCAT(moviesgenre.genre) as genres
FROM movies, genre
WHERE FIND_IN_SET(moviesgenre.ID, Movies.genre)>0
GROUP BY Movies.ID
```

But this solution is not raccommended because when your DB size increase, you will have performance decreasing, and encounter other difficulties.

Comment: @Strawberry the abuse of the downvotes is equal to the abuse of SQL. I'm the one that approved your normalization suggestion, but FIND_IN_SET and GROUP_CONCAT are functions available in MySQL. Why don't we have to use them and understand if they should be fine for our purposes and context?

Comment: @Strawberry Ok, you are probably right, I will add the normalization needed

Comment: I still have issues with GROUP_CONCAT, but I accept that this correctly satisfies the requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You have to join the two tables on the genre id in the genre list in the movies table. An group concatenation on the genre name is to be done. Here is the query:

```
SELECT A.ID, A.Title, A.Genre, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT B.GENRE SEPARATOR ',') GenreNames
FROM Movies A LEFT JOIN moviesgenre B
ON LOCATE(B.ID,A.Genre) > 0
GROUP BY A.ID, A.Title, A.Genre;
```

For more info see:

[MySQL LOCATE() Function](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_locate.asp)

[MySQL GROUP_CONCAT Function](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-group_concat/)

Comment: Please leave a comment why you think my answer is wrong, don't just simply downvote.